# Splitting Columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

I want to ask a complicated question and I think its advanced a little.

I have a table has this design, its an attendance system. I need to split the time if the attendance count per day was not 2:

```
id    pd     time        date
1     5      07:05       08/07/2014
2     4      18:02       07/07/2014
3     1      07:05       06/07/2014
4     1      07:06       06/07/2014
5     1      18:00       06/07/2014
```

I need to add them to a table in the database and to be split in that form with respect the pd and date

```
id   pd     time1     time2       time3    ....     date
1    5      07:05                                   08/07/2014
2    4      18:02                                   07/07/2014
3    1      07:05     07:06       18:00             06/07/2014
```

it would be great if you can help me :)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. What do you mean by "attendance count"? And by "not 2"? It looks to me like you mean "more than 1".

Comment: I can't provide you with a precise answer because you haven't tagged the question with what platform you're on. Generally, though, add a row number for each row (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [date], pd ORDER BY time) in T-SQL), then pivot the result based on this row number (PIVOT in T-SQL). If you google the exact syntax of those two, that should get you started.

Comment: Iam creating a web application based on attendance system . am using mysql and php . i have a table for every employee that has took attendance and they keep adding when the employees takes attendance on the machine . i extracted the employees that has has attendance 2 times per day which are in and out . and i added them to a table with columns that in and out . now i want to extract the attendances for the employees that has took attendance 1 per day or more than 2 per day which they are error and i want to add them to a table employee time1 time2 time3 ...

Comment: Colin't Hart , i mean that i want to extract the attendace for every employee that has took attendance per day 1 time or more than 2 , because if it was 2 so the employee has took attendance correctly , and i did that . now i have extracted the error log which are attendance !=2 . now i need to add them to a table like i have drawn . am sorry my english isnt that good , i wish you have understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my limited mysql knowledge, I don't think you can use PIVOT or ROW_NUMBER(), so here's a more generic suggestion on how to solve your problem:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, pd,
       MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=1 THEN time END)) AS time1,
       MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=2 THEN time END)) AS time2,
       MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=3 THEN time END)) AS time3,
       ...
       MIN((CASE WHEN ordinal=99 THEN time END)) AS time99
FROM (
      SELECT t.id, t.pd, t.time, t.date,
             (SELECT 1+COUNT(*)
              FROM someTable AS sub
              WHERE sub.pd=t.pd AND
                    sub.date=t.date AND (
                    sub.time<t.time OR
                    sub.time=t.time AND sub.id<t.id)) AS ordinal
      FROM someTable AS t
     ) AS x
GROUP BY pd, date;
```

As you can see, it contains an ugly self-referencing subquery and hard-coded columns. My recommendation is that you should probably look for ways to solve this problem in the application layer, by returning the table data properly sorted:

```
SELECT id, pd, date, time
FROM someTable
ORDER BY pd, date, time;
```

... and then ordering and formatting the columns in the application.

Comment: thanks alot bro its almost the answer, the problem in your code that if there is a duplicate in pd and date and time it doesnt show in the table , and i need to show it because it could be the employee check in and check out at the same time, i need to show them . it could be great if you can fix it and it would be a complete answer , and Daniel hutmacher you're prof :)

Comment: I see. Ok, I've added some code to resolve duplicates using the id column, which I presume is an incrementing primary key. Hope that works for you!

Comment: thanks sir its an amazing answer , i just need a query to extract the error logs if you can please, i need to extract if the employee has just checked in or if he checked in and out then in . means if time for pd and for same date was 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9 . it would be really great from you :)

Comment: And i need to extract the correct logs please , which are the pd which is the employee per day has took attendance 2 time 4 time 6 time 8 time . it would be great :)